# How to verify tooltip text using Selenium WebDriver with java on a webpage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

I want to verify tooltip text on NEW Button of my webpage. The html backend code of NEW Button before mousehover is as below:

```
<button id="newBtn" class="checkForSave" title="Create a new Configuration Package" type="button">New</button>
```

After mousehover on NEW Button the html backend code of NEW Button is as below:

```
<button id="newBtn" class="checkForSave" title="" type="button"> area-describdby="ui-tooltip-27"New</button>
```

Now I want to verify that tooltip text "Create a new Configuration Package" should come after mousehover on NEW Button.

I'm able to store the text in a string before mouseover by following code:

```
WebElement NewButton = driver.findElement(By.id("newBtn"));
String Tooltip = NewButton.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(Tooltip);
```

Its printing text "Create a new Configuration Package"

But when I'm moving mouse over NEW button and writing code

```
Actions ActionChains = new Actions(driver);
WebElement NewButton = driver.findElement(By.id("newBtn"));
actions.moveToElement(NewButton).build().perform();
ActionChains.clickAndHold(NewButton).perform();
String Tooltip = NewButton.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(Tooltip);
```

I'm not geting anything i m getting blank message Because after mousehover the title is "" in backend html code of NEW Button.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's really tricky to get the tooltip text as the title becomes blank as ""

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line ActionChains.clickAndHold(NewButton).perform();

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Mouse;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;

Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) webEleObj;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) getDriver()).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find element using xpath! It may help you as the same thing i tried with "id" & it didn't work, while it worked using xpath instead!!